# How do i import the saved module in Google Colab?

Tags: nlp, google-colaboratory, spacy

I was build a NER module using Spacy in Google Colab. I saved it to the disk using nlp.to_disk() function.

`nlp.to_disk("RCM.model")`

This module is saved under the files. How should i import the RCM module for testing purpose?

i have tried the below code but it didn't work.

```
from google.colab import drive
my_module = drive.mount('/content/RCM.model', force_remount=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save a model you can load it using `spacy.load`.

```
import spacy

spacy.load("RCM.model") # the argument should be the path to the directory
```